# Setting up the proxy for rstudio

Tags: r

My machine is running on Ubuntu 14.04, and I have already tried looking at [Configuring R to Use an HTTP Proxy](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200488488-Configuring-R-to-Use-an-HTTP-Proxy) in the FAQ section of Rstudio support.

This is what I did till now...

in my home directory, I created a file named .Renviron with the following contents

```
http_proxy = http:// ip_address : port_num/
http_proxy_user = username : password
```

then in the rstudio, I tried to install swirl package

```
> install.packages("swirl")
Warning in install.packages :
  cannot open: HTTP status was '403 Forbidden'
Warning in install.packages :
  cannot open: HTTP status was '403 Forbidden'
Warning in install.packages :
  unable to access index for repository http://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib
Installing package into ‘/home/dmacs/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.1’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
  cannot open: HTTP status was '403 Forbidden'
Warning in install.packages :
  cannot open: HTTP status was '403 Forbidden'
Warning in install.packages :
  unable to access index for repository http://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘swirl’ is not available (for R version 3.1.2)
```

and there I see all this stuff, but I am able to access the link http://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib from my browser.

I even tried setting up the proxy using GUI based rstudio, but I couldn't figure out where was the option to set the proxy.

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Swaroop

You should add proxy information to your Renviron.site file that is located ‘R_HOME/etc/Renviron.site’. You can find your R_HOME by call bellow command on RStudio console.

```
> R.home()
[1] "/usr/lib/R"
```

Add you proxy server address in ‘R_HOME/etc/Renviron.site’

```
http_proxy=http://<<your proxy server address>>/
```

and restart RStudio.

Good luck.

Ky Ryu