# Installing r-packages in RStudio with proxy

Tags: proxy, r

I am using:

- Ubuntu 15.04
- RStudio 0.99.486.
- R 3.1.2
- proxy network with authentication

The problem occurs when I open RStudio and try to install any package.
Example:

`install.packages("ggplot2")`

I get the following error:

```
Installing package into ‘/home/eisti/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.1’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘ggplot2’ is not available (for R version 3.1.2)`
```

I tried to follow [steps from official support](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200488488-Configuring-R-to-Use-an-HTTP-or-HTTPS-Proxy) and I've seen this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/572722/setting-up-the-proxy-for-rstudio?newreg=e6e7e18d70b64c87ab636cf56cc10819) and bunch of other things on Internet, but nothing helps me. 
BTW everything works fine on Windows.

Any help will be highly appreciated. Merci.

Answer (score 1):

I've found already the answer. Every time I launch RStudio, the first thing I have to do is executing the following command:

```
Sys.setenv(http_proxy="http://user:password@proxy.com:port/")
```

Then I can install packages.

Comment: you can also put the following into a file at `~/.Renviron`: `http_proxy="http://user:password@proxy.com:port/"`. This will set the environment variable for your proxy each time you start R. See `?Startup`.